# Excel recognize wrong object at runtime when userform is setup

Tags: excel, vba, controls, runtime, userform

I have this code initialize an userform. It crashes Excel sometimes (there are times it doesn't crash :|). After awhile of hunting, it turns out that the code get error because Excel recognizes a `Frame` as a `CommandButton`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
EntryFormInitialization
End Sub

Public Sub OpenEntryForm()
If entrySh Is Nothing Then Set entrySh = Sheets("Data Entry")
ResetFormulaSheet (False)
If Not CheckShapeExist(picNameDefault) Then InsertDoc
entrySh.Shapes("Cover").OnAction = ""
entrySh.Shapes("Cover").Visible = msoCTrue
entrySh.Shapes("Cover").ZOrder msoBringToFront
entrySh.Shapes(picNameDefault).ZOrder msoBringToFront
Sheets("Data Entry").ScrollArea = ""
EntryForm.Show
ResizeEntryForm
End Sub

Sub EntryFormInitialization
'more codes
    Debug.Print TypeName(EntryForm.FrameGoods) 'Return CommandButton in the 2nd image.
    With EntryForm.FrameGoods 'Code stopped here in screenshot.
    .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical 'Crashes here
    .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 8.5
    .ScrollWidth = .InsideWidth * 9
    End With
'more codes
End Sub
```

It turns out that the object `EntryForm.FrameGoods` is recognized as commandbutton at runtime. I have no idea why that would happen as it's a manually drawn control. This have dragged me down for 2 days. I can list things that I tried but most of them would sound stupid because it clearly wouldn't work but I was at my wit's end. What can I do in this case?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Couple of thoughts, no real strong basis for why either would work ... 1. Try using `With Me.FrameGoods` in `EntryFormInitialization` to see if that changes anything; 2. Try renaming FrameGoods (to anything else) and then compiling (ie let the compiler find an error) then go through and fix your code by changing all of the code references (don't forget to change for any event handlers, if any) to the new name you used. Could also try this for the particular CommandButton if that one CommandButton seems to be linked to the problem.

Comment: @JohnM the method `EntryFormInitialization` is in a module, not in the form's code so I cannot use `Me.Something`. But I am considering moving those code into the form's code. I usually prefer to only contain callers in the form's code to see easier.

Comment: Try exporting the form to disk, removing the form from the project and saving the project.  Then import the form back into the project.

Comment: @igittr I tried the steps you described, it doesn't work. It still crashes for the exact same reason.

Comment: Did you try my second point (renaming)?